# get the somme of checkbox checked in dataGridView1 c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, count

how I can get the somme of ckecked in my datagridview, exemple:

**if I check adrian in column 3 I'll get adrian = 1, if i check colomn 4 too, I'll get adrian = 2, but nicola have 0**

see the picture

http://s27.postimg.org/b7dg9znub/image.jpg

please how i can do that ?

Comment: Write a javascript on checkbox onclick event. Declare global counter variable and increment the counter when a check box is checked is true other wise decrements the counter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do like this

```
check = new Guid(grddata.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Gid"].Value.ToString());
check1 = grddata.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
```